# pgfgantt package - Timeout: Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02)

Tags: packages, compiling, pgfgantt

I am trying to compile a tex file that should display a gantt chart made with the help of the pgfgantt package.

During compilation I get the line *Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02)* and afterwards tex seems to stop compiling (even though it is still in compiling mode). My code is a slight alteration of what some other user poster here: [Gantt chart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63877/gantt-chart-package)

For clarification: I want to have more than one bar in the same task line. I want to indicate a repeating task.

This my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ftbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
vgrid,hgrid, 
title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=.05,
title right shift=-.05,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=0.7,
group right shift=0,
group top shift=.6,
group height=.3,
group peaks={}{}{.2}]{24}
%labels
\gantttitle{Work Plan}{24}\\
\gantttitle{Year 1}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 2}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 3}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 4}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 5}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 6}{4}\\
%tasks
\ganttbar{Task9}{1}{2}
\ganttbar{}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Task8}{2}
\ganttbar{}{4}
\ganttbar{}{6}
\ganttbar{}{8} 
\ganttbar{}{10}
\ganttbar{}{12}
\ganttbar{}{14}
\ganttbar{}{16}
\ganttbar{}{18}
\ganttbar{}{20}\\
\ganttbar{Task7}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task6}{8}
\ganttbar{}{16}
\ganttbar{}{20} \\
\ganttbar{Task5}{9}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task4}{15}
\ganttbar{19} \\
\ganttbar{Task3}{17}{18} \\
\ganttbar{Task2}{19}{24}\\
\ganttbar{Task1}{21}{23}


\end{ganttchart}
\end{center}
\caption{Gantt Chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before it looped you would have had the error message

```
! Use of \\ganttbar doesn't match its definition.
```

It is best not to ignore TeX errors, the default recovery usually does something wrong.

`\gantbar` takes three arguments and in most cases you only gave it two. This runs without error although I made up the numbers. There is no `f` option for floats so I removed that as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
vgrid,hgrid, 
title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=.05,
title right shift=-.05,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=0.7,
group right shift=0,
group top shift=.6,
group height=.3,
group peaks={}{}{.2}]{24}
%labels
\gantttitle{Work Plan}{24}\\
\gantttitle{Year 1}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 2}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 3}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 4}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 5}{4} 
\gantttitle{Year 6}{4}\\
%tasks
\ganttbar{Task9}{1}{2}
\ganttbar{}{4}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Task8}{1}{2}
\ganttbar{}{2}{4}
\ganttbar{}{5}{6}
\ganttbar{}{7}{8} 
\ganttbar{}{9}{10}
\ganttbar{}{11}{12}
\ganttbar{}{13}{14}
\ganttbar{}{15}{16}
\ganttbar{}{17}{18}
\ganttbar{}{19}{20}\\
\ganttbar{Task7}{6}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task6}{7}{8}
\ganttbar{}{15}{16}
\ganttbar{}{19}{20} \\
\ganttbar{Task5}{9}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task4}{14}{15}
\ganttbar{19}{19}{19} \\
\ganttbar{Task3}{17}{18} \\
\ganttbar{Task2}{19}{24}\\
\ganttbar{Task1}{21}{23}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{center}
\caption{Gantt Chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```