# Rotate Gantt Chart Figure

Tags: rotating, pgfgantt

This is a follow up question to:

[Gantt chart package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63877/gantt-chart-package/106350#106350)

any ideas on how to rotate the gantt chart to make it appear sidewards? (i.e. rotate it 90 degrees?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the landscape-option to turn your page, like this:

```
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    ...your Gantt-Chart here
    \end{landscape}
 \end{document}
```

To rotate it clockwise, you need to use `rotating` package:

```
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \begin{document}
     \begin{rotate}{270}
        ...your Gantt-Chart here
     \end{rotate}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, wish it was the silver bullet! Unfortunately I get an error message: Environment landscape undefined.

Comment: @user1249957 `\usepackage{lscape}` to make `landscape` environment work. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp] 
    ... 
\end{sidewaystable}
```