# Gantt chart - set width of descriptions to be the same across charts

Tags: formatting, pgfgantt, gantt

Hello and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

I have a \pgfgantt chart that I need to split into a couple as it's too long (I'm using the latest version of \pgfgantt installed yesterday). I'd like to align the charts by their border; I thought maybe inserting 'dummy text' would work but I don't know how to do that. Do you have any suggestions? And if anything jumps out at you in the code (apart from August hanging out on its lonesome for a day) please let me know, I'm still very much learning.[image]

Thanks again.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
    \usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}   
        \centering

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%            Gantt 1             %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{ganttchart}%
            [time slot format = {isodate},% Specify the date format (yyyy-mm-dd)
            x unit = 2.1 mm,
            y unit title = 10 mm,
            y unit chart = 4 mm
            ]%
            {2021-03-01}% Specify start date
            {2021-05-16} % Specify end date 1
            \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week}%\\
            \ganttnewline
            \ganttbar{Something quite long that's going on}{2021-03-08}{2021-03-14}\\
            \ganttnewline
            \ganttmilestone{Do another relatively wordy thing}{2021-03-08}\\
        \end{ganttchart}
    
        \vfill
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%            Gantt 2             %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{ganttchart}%
            [time slot format = {isodate},% Specify the date format (yyyy-mm-dd)
            x unit = 2.1 mm,
            y unit title = 10 mm,
            y unit chart = 4 mm
            ]%
            {2021-05-17}% Specify start date
            %       {2021-05-16} % Specify end date 1
            {2021-08-01} % End date 2
            %   {2021-11-26}% Specify end date
            \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week}%\\
            \ganttnewline
            \ganttbar{Thing 3}  {2021-05-17}{2021-07-11}
        \end{ganttchart}
    
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Alternative solution.
- Use `\makebox` to have an effective width of zero for the labels!
- I added `showframe` to show the page borders.
- If you manage to narrow down the chart then it may look good.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

% http://www-hermes.desy.de/latex/ltx-262.html
% \makebox[width][position]{text}

\begin{figure}
\centering
% Chart 1
    \begin{ganttchart}%
        [time slot format = {isodate},
        x unit = 1.8mm,
        y unit title = 10mm,
        y unit chart = 4mm
        ]%
        {2021-03-01}
        {2021-05-16}
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week}%\\
        \ganttnewline
        \ganttbar{\makebox[0mm][r]{text text}}{2021-03-08}{2021-03-14}\\
        \ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone{\makebox[0mm][r]{text}}{2021-03-08}\\
    \end{ganttchart}\\
% Chart 2
    \begin{ganttchart}%
        [time slot format = {isodate},
        x unit = 1.8mm,
        y unit title = 10mm,
        y unit chart = 4mm
        ]%
        {2021-05-17}
        {2021-08-01}
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week}%\\
        \ganttnewline
        \ganttbar{\makebox[0mm][r]{text text text}}{2021-05-17}{2021-07-11}
    \end{ganttchart}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't give you an up vote (I lack the stack exchange cred) but that looks a promising solution! Thanks very much, I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @hacktacular42 Maybe u can accept the answer so that the "case" can be closed.

Comment: @ Dr. Manuel Kuehner, sorry I actually had to look up how to do that, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

- I do *not* have a solution: Maybe somebody else can build on top of it.
- I tried to combine the following posts.
- [Subcaption vertical alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204299)
- [Rotate Gantt Chart Figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106353)
- [Subcaption: Vertical alignment of two images of different vertical size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239128)
- [Figures: What is the difference between using subfig or subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314)
- But I was not successful. It seems like the size of the ganttchart is not known to the LaTeX system.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newsavebox{\myLargestImage}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204299
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106353
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239128
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    % Step 1
    \savebox{\myLargestImage}{%
    \begin{rotate}{90}
    \begin{ganttchart}%
        [time slot format = {isodate},
        x unit = 2.1 mm,
        y unit title = 10 mm,
        y unit chart = 4 mm
        ]%
        {2021-03-01}
        {2021-05-16}
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week}%\\
        \ganttnewline
        \ganttbar{Something quite long that's going on}{2021-03-08}{2021-03-14}\\
        \ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone{Do another relatively wordy thing}{2021-03-08}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
    \end{rotate}
    }
    % Step 2
    \usebox{\myLargestImage}
\hspace{25mm}
\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\myLargestImage-\height}{%
    %
    \begin{rotate}{90}
    \begin{ganttchart}%
        [time slot format = {isodate},
        x unit = 2.1 mm,
        y unit title = 10 mm,
        y unit chart = 4 mm
        ]%
        {2021-05-17}
        {2021-08-01}
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week}%\\
        \ganttnewline
        \ganttbar{Thing 3}  {2021-05-17}{2021-07-11}
    \end{ganttchart}
    \end{rotate}
    %
    }
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into that for me Dr Kuehner. I used flush right, obviously it's not centred in the page so not ideal but at least the two edges line up which looks a touch better.