# How can I create a Gantt / Sankey diagram combination?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pgfgantt

Is there a package that would help me create a diagram such as the one below?
The example diagram can be found in [this PATHOCOM project proposal](https://figshare.com/articles/preprint/PATHOCOM_proposal/13174337).
It appears to be a combination of a Gantt and Sankey diagram. An example of how this can be drawn containing just "Aim 1", "Site", "Sampling" should be enough to get me started.

[image]

Comment: It looks nice but you should really provide a MWE so that the potential helpers here would not need typing your text (at least).

Comment: The diagram is doesn't contain my text, though I linked to it. `\lorem` text would be absolutely fine for an example.

Comment: Ok for the text that you don't need (but how should we know ?). My point is : help us to help you by providing something we can copy/paste in our editor and start working on :)

Comment: @JeT I clarified the question regarding the answer that would help me.

Comment: In your diagram, all tracks and arrows are the same width. It is therefore not a Sankey diagram.

Comment: Have you seen [pgfgantt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63877/gantt-chart-package)?

Comment: @FHZ Thank you, yes. Rather than the flow arrows of the chart I included as an example, it can display task interdependencies, which are too precise for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**Some comments**
I think a solution for the diagram you are looking for can be achieved using only the `positioning` library:

- I organized all the elements of the drawing around the empty cell in the upper left corner, which is a node.  On its corresponding row and column, all the elements are nodes, say *labels* and *years* respectively.
- The style for a *label* node is `leftn` and for a *year* node is `yearn`.
- The rectangles are created with the `rectangle` command using coordinates (x, y) induced by the nodes (x by *years* and y by *labels*).
- The arrows (style `to`) use the same kind of coordinates; a pre action (to be traced in white) gives the *pass under* effect.
- Note that for aesthetic reasons, when drawing a curved arrow, the starting point (constructed from nodes) must be slightly lowered.
- At the beginning, there are three parameters controlling the width and hight of a *label* node and the number of years.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{%
  real \w, \h;
  integer \N;
  \w = 6;
  \h = 2;
  \N = 6;
}
\tikzset{%
  leftn/.style={#1, minimum width=\w cm, minimum height=\h ex,
    anchor=west, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1ex, text width=\w cm, scale=.85},
  yearn/.style={minimum width=.5*\w cm, inner xsep=0pt, scale=.85, font=\bfseries},
  to/.style={preaction={draw, white, line width=4.5pt, line cap=butt,
      arrows={-Latex[length=4pt, width=10pt]}},
    #1, line width=3pt, line cap=butt,
    arrows={-Latex[length=3pt, width=8pt]}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = .9\baselineskip and 0pt,
  every node/.style={}]

  %% North-West empty node
  \node[leftn, minimum height=\h ex] (NW) {};

  %% year nodes
  \node[right=of NW.east, yearn] (y1) {Year 1};
  \foreach \j [remember=\j as \i (initially 1)]
  in {2, 3, ..., \N}{%
    \node[right=of y\i.east, yearn] (y\j) {Year \j};
  }

  %% blue nodes 1
  \node[below=of NW.south west, leftn={blue}] (nB1) {Site characterization};
  \node[below=of nB1.west, leftn={blue}] (nB2) {Sampling \& sequencing};
  \node[below=of nB2.west, leftn={blue}] (nB3) {Sequence analysis};

  \node[below=of nB3.west, leftn, minimum height=\h ex] (nS1) {};

  %% red nodes 1
  \node[below=of nS1.south west, leftn={red}] (nR1) {Resource development};
  \node[below=of nR1.west, leftn={red}] (nR2) {Phenotyping};
  \node[below=of nR2.west, leftn={red}] (nR3) {Joint GWA mapping};
  \node[below=of nR3.west, leftn={red}] (nR4) {Genetic validation};

  %% rectangles
  \foreach \k in {1, 3, ..., \N}{%
    \fill[blue!60!green!15] (nB1.north west -| y\k.west) rectangle
    (nR4.south west -| y\k.east);
  }

  %% arrows
  \draw[to=blue] (nB1 -| y1.west) -- (nB1 -| y1.east);
  \draw[to=blue] ([yshift=-1.5pt] nB1 -| y1.270)
  to[out=270, in=180] (nB2 -| y1.east) -- (nB2 -| y3.east);
  \draw[to=blue] ([yshift=-1.5pt] nB2 -| y2.270)
  to[out=270, in=180] (nB3 -| y2.east) -- (nB3 -| y4.east);

  \draw[to=red] ([yshift=-1.5pt] nB3 -| y3.270)
  to[out=270, in=180] (nR4 -| y4.east) -- (nR4 -| y6.east);
   
  \draw[to=red] (nR1 -| y1.west) -- (nR1 -| y1.east);
  \draw[to=red] ([yshift=-1.5pt] nR1 -| y1.270)
  to[out=270, in=180] (nR2 -| y1.east) -- (nR2 -| y3.east);
  \draw[to=red] ([yshift=-1.5pt] nR2 -| y2.270)
  to[out=270, in=180] (nR3 -| y2.east) -- (nR3 -| y5.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```